# take out components from array session and save in Database LARAVEL 9

Tags: php, mysql, laravel, session, error-handling

How are you? Hope well. I have e-commerce project on laravel 9. Actually i want to make checkout. I have add to cart function with sessions(it works fine), i want to make checkout. I am recieving cart with sessions

```
 $order = session('cart');
 var_dump($order);
```

This is working fine. It makes output with array('title','price','quantity'). Actually i want to put out each other and next save it in database.

```
array(1) { [52]=> array(3) { ["title"]=> string(11) "MacBook Pro" ["quantity"]=> int(1) 
["price"]=> string(7) "2399.99" } }
```

This is array, which i have in checkout page. Please help me. I want to put out each other, for example: $order_title = ....
$order_price = ...
$order_quantity = ...
and next save it in database, table named 'orders'.

Comment: You should probably follow a tutorial. This question is too open-ended for SO.

Comment: no, i want to take out each components from array and next save it in db.

Comment: please say to me tutorial if you know

Comment: @waterloomatt please

Comment: @waterloomatt , Actually i want to make checkout. I have add to cart which is with sessions, and i have array of cart in in checkout page, array contains title, price, quantity,  i want to put out each from array and make output and next save it in database

Answer (score 0):

Just insert / add the data how you do normally.

```
$carts = session('cart');

foreach($carts as $cart)
{
    Order::create([
       'order_title' => $cart['title'],
       'order_quantity' => $cart['quantity'],
       'order_price' => $cart['price'],
      
   ]);
}
```

Answer (score 0):

first read data from session then iterate through elements of array and save them:

```
$carts = session('cart');

foreach($carts as $cart) {
    $order = new Order();
    $order->order_title = $cart['title'];
    $order->order_quantity = $cart['quantity'];
    $order->order_price = $cart['price'];
    $order->save();
}
```